# Field Integrity Exception for Name

Tags: custom-object, metadata-api, exception, standard-field

I am trying to create a Related List with a custom object using the Metadata API. When I make the call I get a Field Integrity Exception saying that the field "Name" does not exist on my object. However, when I go to the object in Setup -> Create -> Object I clearly see Name as one of the standard fields.

Comment: Are you able to specify name in UI? for example contact object has field name. But it consist of firstname & lastname. Where field name is read only.

Comment: What do you mean by "specify name in UI"? I can add the field "Name" to the layout for this object if that is what you are referring to. Although it is also read only like the Contact object. Would that prevent me from being able to put that as a field on related list though?

Comment: can you try to save NAME in capital

Comment: Louis, can you share with us some of the code you're using?

Comment: It the name field type set to autonumber?

Comment: Yes the name is set to autonumber. I also found out that when I capitalize the field, Name, it will successfully add the field.